# AngularJS custom query on rest api: Error in resource configuration for action `get`

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-resource, ngresource

My users and admins are stored in a single collection. All the REST api operations are the same for them, but I'd like to be able to query the list of users and the list of admins separately. (I don't want to query the full list of users and sort them in the client when I only need the list of admins). So on the server side I made a custom url just for querying admins:

```
/api/users
/api/users/admins
```

On the client side I made a custom method for the Users resource to retrieve the admins only:

```
// Users service used for communicating with the users REST endpoint
angular.module('users').factory('Users', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('api/users/:userId', {
            userId: '@_id'
        }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            admins: {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'api/users/admins',
                isArray: true
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

This works fine, when I first query() the resource, and the admin list is displayed on `users/admins`. After I load a single admin (which opens under the `/users/:userId` url) and I try to navigate back to `users/admins`, it sends a GET request to get the admin list (array of objects as expected) and I get the following error:

Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$resource/badcfg?p0=get&p1=object&p2=array

If I click on the Admin List menu item, and load the state that way, there is no error and the view loads fine.

I also tried to create a separate resource just for querying the admins, but the same error remains:

```
angular.module('users').factory('Admins', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('api/users/admins');
    }
]);
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to handle these custom queries?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, all the above seems to be correct, it turned out that the problem was in the $stateProvider configuration.

As the user view state was defined earlier than the admin list state, the `/users/:userId` param picked up the `/users/admin` url when the state was looked up by url, instead of state name. That state was expecting a single user object instead of an array of users.

```
state('admin.users.view', {
    url: '/:userId',
    templateUrl: 'modules/users/views/view-user.client.view.html'
}).
state('admin.users.admins', { //extra view for listing admin profiles
    url: '/admins',
    parent: 'admin.users',
    templateUrl: 'modules/users/views/list-admins.client.view.html'
}).
```

The solution was to change the order and define the admin list state earlier:

```
state('admin.users.admins', { //extra view for listing admin profiles
    url: '/admins',
    parent: 'admin.users',
    templateUrl: 'modules/users/views/list-admins.client.view.html'
}).
state('admin.users.view', {
    url: '/:userId',
    templateUrl: 'modules/users/views/view-user.client.view.html'
}).
```